# Creating/outputing a binary tree(not BST)

Tags: c++, dictionary, binary-tree

My code (below) works unless the required key isn't in the list yet (so if a node doesn't have a reference to its parent). It ignores the nodes and just makes a tree without them. How can I fix it? I'm thinking about just re-looping once all the keys are in and just keep adding and removing accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct Foo {
  int data{0};
  int left{-1};
  int right{-1};
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Foo& ff) {
  in >> ff.data >> ff.left >> ff.right;
  return in;
}

struct Del {
  template <class T>
  void operator()(T* p) {
    std::cout << "[deleted #" << (p ? p->data : 0) << "]\n";
    delete p;
  }
};

struct Bar {
  int data{0};
  std::unique_ptr<Bar, Del> lef;
  std::unique_ptr<Bar, Del> rig;
};

void print(const std::unique_ptr<Bar, Del>& node) {
  if (node) {
    std::cout << ' ' << node->data;
    print(node->lef);

    print(node->rig);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string input =
      "101 1 3 102 2 8 104 6 7 103 -1 5 109 -1 -1 106 4 -1 107 -1   -1 108 -1 "
      "-1 105 -1 -1";

  std::istringstream IN(input);

  std::map<int, std::pair<Bar*, bool>> mlist;
  std::unique_ptr<Bar, Del> root;
  int row = 0;
  Foo entry;
  while (IN >> entry) {
    if (0 == row) {
      root.reset(new Bar);
      Bar* node = root.get();
      node->data = entry.data;
      std::cout << row << " [created #" << entry.data << ']';
      if (0 <= entry.left)
        mlist.emplace(entry.left, std::make_pair(node, true));
      if (0 <= entry.right)
        mlist.emplace(entry.right, std::make_pair(node, false));

    } else {
      auto it = mlist.find(row);
      if (mlist.end() != it) {
        if (it->second.second) {
          it->second.first->lef.reset(new Bar);
          Bar* node = it->second.first->lef.get();
          node->data = entry.data;
          std::cout << row << " [created #" << entry.data << ']';
          if (0 <= entry.left)
            mlist.emplace(entry.left, std::make_pair(node, true));
          if (0 <= entry.right)
            mlist.emplace(entry.right, std::make_pair(node, false));

          mlist.erase(it);
        } else {
          it->second.first->rig.reset(new Bar);
          Bar* node = it->second.first->rig.get();
          node->data = entry.data;
          std::cout << row << " [created #" << entry.data << ']';
          if (0 <= entry.left)
            mlist.emplace(entry.left, std::make_pair(node, true));
          if (0 <= entry.right)
            mlist.emplace(entry.right, std::make_pair(node, false));

          mlist.erase(it);
        }
        // mlist.erase( it );
      }
    }
    std::cout << " list size " << mlist.size() << '\n';
    ++row;
  }
  std::cout << "final list size " << mlist.size() << "\n\n";
  print(root);
  std::cout << "\n\n";
  std::cout << "Lets see whats left in the list:";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what's the difference between your binary tree and a Binary Search Tree?  My understanding is that in a binary tree, each node may have two subtrees that are not necessarily ordered.

Comment: Yea this is just a binary tree. It isn't ordered at all, but it does follow the two nodes max .

Comment: `root - > Left` doesn't seem valid. Do you mean `root -> Left` (use `->` operator instead of `-` operator and `>` operator)? Why not post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Ok well the code has changed a lot so I have updated the code. I asked someone for help. I am now stuck as to how to fix a node not being created if its parent node hasn't been initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just used a vector of nodes and it worked perfectly. Sorry for all the confusion!